# LastModifiedDate an Hyperlink.address

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to VBA and im trying to make a Macro to get the lastmodified date from a Hyperlink.

I have this code for now

```
Sub ExtractURLs()

Dim lnk As Hyperlink
Dim objFile As Object

Dim fecha As Date


For Each lnk In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks



lnk.Range.Offset(0, 8).Value = FileDateTime(lnk.Address)
    
    
Next lnk

End Sub
```

But the order filedatetime doesnt work, it didnt find the route i dont know why.

I also need that the filedatetime order to be in a specific column range.

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Seems to be working on a quick sample. Did you get an error? If you `Debug.Print lnk.Address`, is the path valid and pointing to the file?

Comment: Hi, if i print the lnk.address it is not the full address printed, the first part of the route is missing

Comment: Then that should be the issue, I believe you need to provide the full path.